# Javascript binary string, to hex, to base58, back to hex, back to string, random error

Tags: javascript, binary, hex, number-formatting, blockchain

I'm learning about Blockchain and wanted to create an example of creating an address, purely for educational purposes - WOULD NOT BE DONE ANYWHERE NEAR PRODUCTION.

Task: create 160 random bits, convert it to hex, convert that to base 58, then to test correctness by reversing the process.

It kind of works, however I get intermittent 'false' on comparison of before and after binary. The hexStringToBinary function returns strings with varying lengths:

```
const bs58 = require('bs58');

//20 * 8 = 160
function generate20Bytes () {
  let byteArray = [];
  let bytes = 0;
  while (bytes < 20) {
    let byte = '';
    while (byte.length < 8) {
      byte += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }
    byteArray.push(byte);
    bytes++;
  }
  return byteArray;
}

//the issue is probably from here
function hexStringToBinary (string) {
  return string.match(/.{1,2}/g)
    .map(hex => parseInt(hex, 16).toString(2).padStart(8, '0'));
}

const addressArray = generate20Bytes();
const binaryAddress = addressArray.join('');
const hex = addressArray.map(byte => parseInt(byte, 2).toString(16)).join('');
console.log(hex);

// then lets convert it to base 58
const base58 = bs58.encode(Buffer.from(hex));
console.log('base 58');
console.log(base58);

// lets see if we can reverse the process
const destructuredHex = bs58.decode(base58).toString();
console.log('hex is the same');
console.log(hex === destructuredHex);

// lets convert back to a binary string
const destructuredAddress = hexStringToBinary(destructuredHex).join('');
console.log('destructured address');
console.log(destructuredAddress);
console.log('binaryAddress address');
console.log(binaryAddress);

//intermittent false/true
console.log(destructuredAddress === binaryAddress);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got round to refactoring with tdd. Realised it wasn't zero filling hex < 16. My [playground repo](https://github.com/roppa/binary-hex-playground)